# simple pagination with this script?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, pagination, glob

Hello stackoverflow I was wondering if it is possible to get a simple pagination thingy with this little script? is it possible to get an example? this script takes all csv files in a folder and shows it on a webpage. The only problem is if the csv has 2000 records each csv then the page crashes. can I like show each csv file on a seperate page?

```
<?php


$arrFiles = glob("../Csv_folder/EMCY_GEN/*.csv");
$arrSortedFiles = array();
foreach($arrFiles as $strFileName) {
   $arrSortedFiles[$strFileName] = filemtime($strFileName);
}
arsort($arrSortedFiles);
foreach(array_keys($arrSortedFiles) as $strFileName)
{

   $file_handle = fopen($strFileName, "r"); 
   echo  "<th><font size='3pt'>".date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($strFileName))."</td></tr></font></th>";
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  
      echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>' ; 
   }  
   fclose($file_handle);  
}

?>
```

Comment: yes, it's possible to do, and yes, you can show each csv separately and no, we're not here to do your job for you. you write some code, we'll maybe help try fix it.

Comment: @MarcB well jeeze thx for ur help highly appreciated. >.> that kinda hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to not have a loop printing out the contents of each CSV. Have an index page that displays the files then link to another page that dynamically loads the CSV.

```
 $arrFiles = glob("../Csv_folder/EMCY_GEN/*.csv");
    $leg = count($arrFiles);
    while($num < $leg){echo $arrFiles[$num]; $num = $num + 1};
```

Comment: Thats the problem I am having actually. Like csv files come in dynamically so the exact number is always different. and they are also getting deleted dynamically. I was trying with something like this http://prntscr.com/6netcj but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Right; so code an index page that displays the files in the directory at that time and allows you to select a CSV to display: